# make mmh3 hash with golang

Tags: go, hash

I want make mmh3 hash with golang!
I found this [pkg](https://github.com/roberson-io/mmh3) but i get runtime error!

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/roberson-io/mmh3"
)

func main() {
    key := []byte("foo")
    var seed uint32 = 0
    hash := mmh3.Hashx86_32(key, seed)
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(hash))
}
```

Comment: Please share the actual error here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem there is some issue in [`roberson-io/mmh3`](https://github.com/roberson-io/mmh3) implementation

Instead you can try [`datadog/mmh3`](https://github.com/datadog/mmh3)

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/datadog/mmh3"
)

func main() {
    key := []byte("foo")
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", mmh3.Hash32(key))
}
```

Or [`reusee/mmh3`](https://github.com/reusee/mmh3)

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/reusee/mmh3"
)

func main() {
    key := []byte("foo")
    h := mmh3.New32()
    h.Write(key)
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", h.Sum(nil))
}
```